# Gitlab push error:The requested URL returned error: 502

Tags: request, gitlab

When I push code to my gitlab, git shows a error as below:
fatal: unable to access 'xxxx.git/': The requested URL returned error: 502

Before that, I always can push/pull successfully. Note that I changed gitlab password once before, but I changed my password back, I don't know whether this change leads to error.

Please help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: A 502 is typically given by a proxy. Are you using a proxy?

Comment: Thanks, I have solved my problem now, because server crashed.